# Differently coloured cells have the same bgColor value

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have some spreadsheets that are basically forms, which are printed, written on in pen by the manufacturing staff, and digitized later for analysis. I am writing a script with openpyxl that collects the digitized data for analysis. Currently, the only analysis is "How often is this box actually filled in and not left blank?".

These forms are subject to change as our manufacturing processes / requirements / etc change, so it's a lot of leg work to change the script every time the form changes. The form is different for each of the parts we produce.

I thought a simple solution would be to require that the spreadsheet have colour in all the cells not intended to be written in, so that the script could pick out all white cells to collect their data.

However, the tools do not seem to do a very good job of identifying cell colour, from what I can tell. The following image is what the sheet looks like (without any text)

[image: Text-free sample spreadsheet]

My code:

```
wb = load_workbook( 'template.xlsx' )
ws = wb.active

print( "A4 bgColor" )
print( ws['A4'].fill.bgColor )
print( "" )

print( "E7 bgColor" )
print( ws['E7'].fill.bgColor )
print( "" )

print( "E8 bgColor" )
print( ws['E8'].fill.bgColor )
print( "" )

print( "F7 bgColor" )
print( ws['F7'].fill.bgColor )
print( "" )

print( "A28 bgColor" )
print( ws['A28'].fill.bgColor )
print( "" )
```

The output:

```
A4 bgColor
<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb=None, indexed=64, auto=None, theme=None, tint=0.0, type='indexed'

E7 bgColor
<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb='00000000', indexed=None, auto=None, theme=None, tint=0.0, type='rgb'

E8 bgColor
<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb=None, indexed=64, auto=None, theme=None, tint=0.0, type='indexed'

F7 bgColor
<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb='00000000', indexed=None, auto=None, theme=None, tint=0.0, type='rgb'

A28 bgColor
<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb=None, indexed=64, auto=None, theme=None, tint=0.0, type='indexed'
```

A4 and A28 were set to some form of grey using what I think are the theme colours in MS Excel. Specifically, `Gray, Accent 3, Lighter 60%`. E7 and F7 were set to `No Fill`, and E8 was set to `White, Background 1`

The problem is that cells A4 and E8 report no differences between their colours. They're both using the colour index 64, which as far as I know, isn't a real thing. Even if it is, the same index is indicating two different colours, so what gives?

I would rather not require that cells be specifically `No Fill` since it requires that anyone making changes to these sheets be aware that White != White, as it were.

---

EDIT:

One suggestion got me to look a bit more closely at the entire `fill` object and I saw that fgColor does something a little bit different. New output using fgColor instead:

```
A4 fgColor
<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb=None, indexed=None, auto=None, theme=6, tint=0.5999938962981048, type='theme'

E7 fgColor
<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb='00000000', indexed=None, auto=None, theme=None, tint=0.0, type='rgb'

E8 fgColor
<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb=None, indexed=None, auto=None, theme=0, tint=0.0, type='theme'

F7 fgColor
<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb='00000000', indexed=None, auto=None, theme=None, tint=0.0, type='rgb'

A28 fgColor
<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb=None, indexed=None, auto=None, theme=6, tint=0.5999938962981048, type='theme'
```

`theme=6` corresponds with the selected grey being in the seventh column of the colour selector, and `tint=0.59999...` corresponds with the "60% lighter" thing excel mentioned.

Should have looked at foreground, not background, I guess...

Comment: You need to check the fill style as well. Also, note that you have some merged cells, which make things even more confusing.

Comment: Not sure if Fill Style is really what I needed to look at, but looking closer at the entire fill object, I did find what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should look for fgColor instead bgColor.